# Haskell Strict fields

Tags: haskell

When defining a lazy field, there is no exception, until you print it.

```
> data T = T Int deriving (Show)
> let t = T undefined
> t
T *** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:3:7 in interactive:Ghci3
```

With strict field (`!Int`), I thought `undefined` would be evaluated right away, which will cause exception, but actually, it's still no evaluated until you print it. Why is that?

```
> data X = X !Int deriving (Show)
> let x = X undefined
> x
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:6:11 in interactive:Ghci5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `let` itself defines a lazy binding -- `let` never evaluates anything by itself (unless `BangPatterns` are used).

```
ghci> let x = undefined
ghci> x
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

You can tell the difference between the strict and lazy constructors like so:

```
ghci> T undefined `seq` ()
()
ghci> X undefined `seq` ()
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```